# How to set default mode for secrets?

Tags: kubernetes

When secrets are created, they are 0755 owned by root:

```
/ # ls -al /var/run/secrets/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            52 Apr 16 21:56 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            21 Apr 16 21:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            28 Apr 16 21:56 eks.amazonaws.com
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            28 Apr 16 21:56 kubernetes.io
```

I want them to be `0700` instead. I know that for regular secret volumes I can use

```
            - name: vol-sec-smtp
              secret:
                defaultMode: 0600
                secretName: smtp
```

and it will mount (at least the secret files themselves) as 0600. Can I achieve the same with the secrets located at `/var/run/secrets` directly from the yaml file?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the default service account token mount and then mount it yourself as you showed.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: automountServiceAccountToken: false

Comment: Like any other secret? The token for each service account is in a secret named `$name-token-$random`. Find the secret and set it in `secretName` like normal.

Comment: `The token for each service account is in a secret named ...` this was part I was missing, thank you! :)

Comment: If you `kubectl get pod -o yaml` any "normal" pod (i.e. without automount false) you'll see it injects an extra volume and volumeMount for you, but they are otherwise not special. The only bit of magic is it looks up the name of the secret for you since that could theoretically change over time if we implement some kind of timed rotation, though it currently doesn't.